# Highcharts labels appears twice

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The labels on my chart appears twice, although the data points are not duplicated.

Any idea how it can be solved?

This is the lables json:

```
labels: {
    rotation: -45,
    formatter: function () {
        var monthStr = Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value);
        var day = Highcharts.dateFormat('%e', this.value);
        var year = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.value - 1);
        return monthStr + " " + day + ", " + year;
    },
    style: {
        color: '#555655',
        fontFamily: 'proximanova-thin',
        fontSize: '17px',
        align: 'center',
        textJustify: 'center'
    },
    x: 0,
    y: 30
}
```

Attached image:
[image]

Comment: If you want one label per day, you need to set your **tickInterval** to one day. Your labels are duplicating because your ticks are more frequent than one day, but the labels are formatted to show only the date. If you format the labels differently to show the time, you'll see that they are not actually repeats.

Comment: @jlbriggs i can't change the labels format, and i tried to add tickInterval for 1 day, it didn't solve the issue (tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highchart x-Axis labels shows double dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185649/highchart-x-axis-labels-shows-double-dates)

Comment: My point about changing the format is that it would demonstrate what's going on - not that it would solve the problem. can you set up a fiddle of the problem? tickInterval should solve it...

Comment: Just in case you placed your option in a wrong place - tickInterval is option of axis. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dthtft3j/

Answer (score 0):

@jlbriggs solved my issue,

adding the interval "tickInterval" solved the issue:

```
tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
```